# Duplicate or unpredictable results in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates

I'm trying to join a few tables in MySQL. Our setup is a little unique so I try to explain as good as I can.

1. I have a table 'INVENTORY' that represents the current items on stock.
2. These items are stored in a table 'COMPONENT'
3. Components are being used in installations.
4. Every user can have multiple installations and the same component can be used in multiple installation as well.
5. To uniquely map a component to an installation, it can be assigned to a PRODUCT. a product as has a 1-1 relationship with an installation. A component is not directly related to an installation
6. To finally assign a product to a specific installation a mapping table COMPOMENT_PRODUCT is used.

**Example:** 
A component is like a part, lets say a screw. This screw is used in a computer. The very same screw can be used on multiple computers. But each computer can only be used on one specific installation.

```
TABLE COMPOMENT_PRODUCT

COMPOMENT_ID    PRODUCT_ID
1               1
1               2
2               1
2               2
```

So we have the components C1 and C2 relevant for two installations.

```
TABLE INVENTORY
COMPOMENT_ID INSTALLATION_ID ON_STOCK
1            1               5
1            2               2
```

**What I want to achieve**
Now, I want to retrieve the inventory state for all components. But, not every component has an inventory record. In these cases, the ON_STOCK value from the inventory shall be NULL

That means, for this example I'd expect the following results

```
COMPOMENT_ID PRODUCT_ID ON_STOCK
1            1          5
1            2          2
2            1          NULL
2            2          NULL
```

But executing this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
COMPONENT_PRODUCT.COMPONENT_ID,
COMPONENT_PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID,
INVENTORY.ON_STOCK

FROM INVENTORY

RIGHT JOIN COMPONENT_PRODUCT ON COMPONENT_PRODUCT.COMPONENT_ID = 
INVENTORY.COMPONENT_ID
```

returns the following resultset:

```
COMPONENT_ID    PRODUCT_ID  ON_STOCK
1               1           5
1               2           5
1               1           2
1               2           2
2               1           (null)
2               2           (null)
```

Now, my next thought was, "of course, this is how joins behave, okay I need to group the results". But the way SQL works, the aggregation is not entirely predictable. SO when I

```
GROUP BY COMPONENT_PRODUCT.COMPONENT_ID,COMPONENT_PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID
```

I get this result:

```
COMPONENT_ID    PRODUCT_ID  ON_STOCK
1               1           5
1               2           5
2               1           (null)
2               2           (null)
```

I have prepared a Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71ca87

What am I forgetting here? Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: So items and components are the same thing? As are products and installations?

Comment: Yes and no. Items and components are the same, installations and product are not the same. Components are basically parts that are being used on installations. As the same component can be used on multiple installations we need a way to determine on which installations the components are used. 

This is done with products. A product can only be used on one installation and a component is a part of that product.

Comment: OK, I still can't figure out *why* you expect the result that you do. :-( Oh, and note that no one ever uses RIGHT JOIN. Just sayin'. It also doesn't help human readability that everything is a 1 or 2 or a 3. Maybe products could start at 100, say and installations at 1000.

Comment: "Component C1 and C2 are used on installation I1, I2." and the table "INVENTORY" contradicts "A component is not directly related to an installation". So it is already unclear how a component "1" can have 2 different values for on_stock. Assuming your model is correct, your problem is your join (it already lists wrong stock values, they won't disappear if you group). But since you already have a table with all allowed combinations, it seems all you need to do is use the table `COMPOMENT_PRODUCT` and left join it with the inventory table (via the 1:1 product-installation-relation).

Comment: The purpose of `GROUP BY` is to compute aggregate values (using the [aggregate (GROUP BY) functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html), not to remove the duplicates. It doesn't even return rows from the table, it **generates** the rows it returns. And, btw, the aggregation is entirely predictable. It doesn't work as expected when one does not use the aggregation functions and expects the engine read their mind and pick a certain value from a set of values. Your `GROUP BY` query is not valid and this is why its results are not predictable.

Comment: As I said, our model is pretty unique and it's hard to explain it in a nutshell. 

I am very reluctant with right joins but in this use case it's necessary. Anyhow, a component is indeed not directly related to an installation. 

A component is like a part, e.g. a screw. A screw can be used in a product, e.g. a computer. Now, the very same screw can be used on multiple computers. But each individual computer can only be used on a specific installation. 

This is why i expect the same screw multiple times in the inventory. I want to know how many screws I have on each computer.

Comment: Nobody uses `RIGHT JOIN` because `RIGHT JOIN` is a redundant feature of the language. Everybody swap the tables and use `LEFT JOIN` instead. Even the [MySQL engine works this way](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/outer-join-simplification.html).

Comment: Every RIGHT JOIN has a logically equivalent LEFT JOIN counterpart (although I accept that in more complex queries it can be hard to see how to construct that counterpart)

Comment: You get extra rows in the `JOIN` query because it doesn't contain the link between products and installations. Put this link into the query (it probably is another table) and the corresponding `ON` conditions and you'll get the results you need, without using `DISTINCT` (it doesn't help here, anyway).

Comment: How do we determine when to keep '5' and when to keep '2'?

Comment: I do know that. The reason why we use right join here this is inheritence. We have a base Inventory Object and an InventoryView object that inherits part of the queries that are being generated. That is the sole reason why we use a right join here.

Comment: (Incidentally, I don't think a database of components, assemblies, and installations is particularly unusual)

Comment: Bingo: Indeed the link between product and installation was missing. 

Moving the inventory join down and adding 

left  JOIN INVENTORY ON COMPONENT_PRODUCT.COMPONENT_ID = INVENTORY.COMPONENT_ID AND INVENTORY.INSTALLATION_ID = INSTALLATION.INSTALLATION_ID

make the results a lot better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT DISTINCT
COMPONENT_PRODUCT.COMPONENT_ID,
COMPONENT_PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID,
INVENTORY.ON_STOCK
FROM INVENTORY
RIGHT JOIN COMPONENT_PRODUCT ON COMPONENT_PRODUCT.COMPONENT_ID = 
INVENTORY.COMPONENT_ID
AND COMPONENT_PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID = INVENTORY.INSTALLATION_ID
```